# Why does this Nginx config result in "rewrite or internal redirection cycle"

Tags: nginx

I've got the following Nginx config:

```
server {
  listen   80;
  server_name  mercury;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/mercury.access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/mercury.error.log;

  location /static {
    add_header Cache-Control: max-age=31536000;
  }

  location / {
    root   /opt/the-jam/www/dist/;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    add_header Cache-Control: max-age=60;
  }
}
```

And I've got the directory structure:

```
§ tree /opt/the-jam/www/dist
/opt/the-jam/www/dist
├── index.html
└── static
    ├── 3522b60dabd4468d03f8.css
    └── 3522b60dabd4468d03f8.js
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
2015/10/20 14:25:26 [error] 4529#0: *95 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 0.0.0.0, server: the-jam, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "the-jam.example.com", referrer: "http://the-jam.example.com/"
```

This is a single-page app where any request, i.e. `/foo/bar/baz` should just load `/index.html`, unless it's requesting something in `/static/[hash].js`, so my understanding is that the `try_files` directive will try load the file at `/foo/bar/baz`, and then fall back to `/index.html`, so why am I getting the redirection cycle?

Comment: `root` should be under `server`, not `location`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with your config is that if `/index.html` cannot be found, it will redirect to `/index.html`. Such configurations are better to avoid, even if you are sure that the file is here.  A configuration like this don't have this problem:

```
root /opt/the-jam/www/dist/;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    ...
}

location = /index.html {
    # no try_files here
    ...
}
```

With such configuration you also will be able to see what's wrong with `/index.html` and why it can't be accessed. My best guess is that access rights on some intermediate directories doesn't allow nginx to access `/opt/the-jam/www/dist/index.html`.